# Adding custom error messages to a ModelForm field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is there a way to add a custom error message to a model field without declaring it in the form as a form field? Is this possible?

I don't want to declare the field again, for example

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    test = models.URLField(max_length = 200)

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    test = forms.URLField(max_length = 200, error_messages={'required' : 'Custom error message'})
    class Meta:
        model = models.test
```

Is there a way to provide a custom error message without defining it again in the form?

**Edited Model**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField(verify_exists = False, max_length = 225, error_messages={'required' : 'Link cannot be left blank.'})
```

**Edit**

I should clarify that I also have a model form for my model. This is the actual code

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 225, error_messages={'required' : 'cannot be left blank'})
    link = models.URLField(verify_exists = False, max_length = 225, error_messages={'required' : ugettext_lazy(u"Link cannot be left blank.") })
```

form

```
class StoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Story
        fields = ('title', 'link')

    def clean_link(self):
        link = self.cleaned_data['link']
        return link.strip()

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        return title.strip()
```

I don't want to declare the fields in my form because then I run into this issue discussed here

[Cleaning data which is of type URLField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653423/cleaning-data-which-is-of-type-urlfield)

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13693

Answer (score 0):

By setting [error_messages in model fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#error-messages) for example.

Comment: I tried that but I cannot get it work. If I leave the field blank it always says "Thie field is required". This is what I had     link = models.URLField(verify_exists = False, max_length = 225, error_messages={'required' : 'Link cannot be left blank.'})

Comment: There was an open ticket in django (http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13693). I fixed it using the patch.

Comment: Yup, was just looking at it...  It doesn't seem to work. I would rather use workaround then patch Django if i were you.